# tracker-extract repeatedly core dumping and crashing

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, journalctl

I was doing the recommended maintenance work as advised [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Logfiles). I ran the command `sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb`, I see that `tracker-extract` is repeatedly crashing and dumping core. I am not sure what to do. Please help me.

Followig is a part of output generated by `sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb`.

[image]

I am using Arch Linux, with Gnome DE.

Comment: Not a solution but might help you: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/tracker/-/issues/254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably during the migration process from *tracker* to *track3* something goes wrong.

Clean tracker database (`$ tracker3 reset`) and any leftover file (`$ rm -rf ~/.cache/tracker{,3}`)

Comment: I didn't upgrade from tracker to tracker3. Although I have tracker installed. Should I uninstall it? I did the above two commands, and also reinstalled tracker{, 3} and tracker-miner{, 3}. Let's see now

Comment: Recently, tracker3 (version 3) overcame tracker (version 2); the former replaced the later, thus I think you have to "clean" your system: remove `tracker{,-miners}` in order to promote `tracker3{,-miners}`

Answer (score 1):

No knowledge of this, but sounds like your problem is seen here

https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2020-05238e0153

So you might want to try the 'solution' seen there i.e. downgrade / upgrade